# What is the best way to select Google search result nodes using HtmlAgilityPack

Tags: html-agility-pack

I am doing a project for a client to analyze Google search results.

I looked at the rendered html and I can get the discreet organic search results using HtmlAgilityPack and this code:

```
HtmlNodeCollection Nodes = HtmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//li[@class='g']");
```

I'm guessing the name of CSS class 'g' is compressed for optimization.
*I am concerned this may change in the future and break the code.*

Is there a better, more robust way of doing this, or is this the best way?

Comment: This XPATH looks reasonably simple, I don't think you'll find a better expression (apart from using the API of course). What you can do is put that string in a configuration file also.

Answer (score 2):

You really really shouldn't get results from google like that since they might just ban you.
A better way would be to use the [Google Custom Search API](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/v1/overview).

It's also unlikely to change in the near future, so you don't have to worry about that either.

Also, from the [Google Terms of Service](http://www.google.com/intl/en/policies/terms/archive/20070416-20120301/):

> 5.3 You agree not to access (or attempt to access) any of the Services by any means other than through the interface that is provided by Google, unless you have been specifically allowed to do so in a separate agreement with Google. You specifically agree not to access (or attempt to access) any of the Services through any automated means (including use of scripts or web crawlers) and shall ensure that you comply with the instructions set out in any robots.txt file present on the Services.

Comment: Although this isn't the answer to your question, I'm pretty much with @shriek. If it's not a special case, you should always try to use the API instead of scraping.

Comment: My first inclination was to use the API.   But I had to consider the possibility that the API uses different algorithms (to prevent reverse engineering) than a user operating a browser.  In which case the results would be different and invalid.